# Removing Cordova logo when iOS app starts

Tags: html, cordova, intel-xdk

I have an HTML5 app developed with Intel XDK. 
It works perfectly on Android, however when I export the app in iOS, a splash screen with the cordova logo appears, and then my own splash screen. I can't find any way to hide this cordova logo when the app starts, any idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can set your desired splash screen images for your project on the Projects Panel under the Cordova 3.X Hybrid Mobile App Settings > Launch Icons and Splash Screens sections. You can import the appropriate images for the desired platforms and dimensions.

Comment: I don't want to specify another splash screen, it is already developer on the HTML code. I want to remove the default cordova splash screen. This means that the app should start directly, in order to show the one that is specified on the code.

Comment: on iOS the launch image is shown before the splash screen, you can avoid it, just change the image as eashtianjr told you to match the one you use on the splash screen

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate it may be very late but I had the same problem and spent a lot of time in finding the solution. 
Somehow it does not seem to be a problem for anybody. But actually the logo is hidden and removing it is not as obvious as you would expect. 
So I will write here my solution so that maybe others can be interested.
Go to index.css and comment the style for  .app{}
i.e.

```
.app {
    background:url(../img/logo.png) no-repeat center top; /* 170px x 200px */
    position:absolute;             /* position in the center of the screen */
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    height:50px;                   /* text area height */
    width:225px;                   /* text area width */
    text-align:center;
    padding:180px 0px 0px 0px;     /* image height is 200px (bottom 20px are overlapped with text) */
    margin:-115px 0px 0px -112px;  /* offset vertical: half of image height and text area height */
                                   /* offset horizontal: half of text area width */
}
```

should become:
    .app{}
I hope it helps